# How to auto-generate suggested requirements from Code Contracts?

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

[Code Contracts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) give me a lot of suggestions from static analysis. Is there some way to auto-generate the suggestions' code (to save time on typing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the team did publish "Code Contracts [Editor extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/85f0aa38-a8a8-4811-8b86-e7f0b8d8c71b/)" but that's all about viewing Contracts.

As far as I know you'll have to just type them in. But start at the lower levels, a lot of information bubbles up and maybe you have to write less than it first appears.